# Seabird_processing CalledProcessError: Command returned non-zero exit status 1

Tags: python, hex, spyder

I am processing CTD data from Seabird in Spyder, but I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\py3compat.py:356 in compat_exec
    exec(code, globals, locals)

  File c:\users\cornelissenl\onedrive - niwa\phd\coding\python files\seabird_processing.py:24
    converter.run(path+"Raw/./AN24_032.hex")

  File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\seabird_processing\configs.py:119 in run
    raise e

  File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\seabird_processing\configs.py:106 in run
    ps = subprocess.run(

  File C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\subprocess.py:571 in run
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,

CalledProcessError: Command '['C:\\Program', 'Files', '(x86)\\Sea-Bird\\SBEDataProcessing-Win32/DatCnvW.exe', '/cC:\\Users\\cornelissenl\\OneDrive', '-', 'NIWA\\PhD\\voyage\\CTD', 'stations\\CTD\\Raw\\AN24_032.xmlcon', '/iC:\\/Users/cornelissenl/OneDrive', '-', 'NIWA/PhD/voyage/CTD', 'stations/CTD/Raw/./AN24_032.hex', '/oC:\\Users\\cornelissenl\\OneDrive', '-', 'NIWA\\PhD\\voyage\\CTD', 'stations\\CTD\\processed\\', '/pC:\\Users\\cornelissenl\\OneDrive', '-', 'NIWA\\PhD\\voyage\\CTD', 'stations\\CTD\\set_up_00.psa', '/a_datcnv', '/s']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

My code is :

```
import seabird_processing as sp


path =  "C:\/Users/cornelissenl/OneDrive - NIWA/PhD/voyage/CTD stations/CTD/"


converter = sp.configs.DatCnvConfig(
    output_dir=path+"./processed", output_file_suffix="_datcnv",
    xmlcon=path+"Raw/./AN24_032.xmlcon", psa=path+"./set_up_00.psa"
)

converter.run(path+"Raw/./AN24_032.hex")
```

Is this an issue with the code or do I need to install something in Spyder/Anaconda?

Thanks!

My (work)laptop is windows.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the full error traceback. It sounds as if this error is being raised somewhere within the Seabird library and therefore either it isn't configured correctly or you aren't using it correctly, but it's impossible to tell that without seeing more detail.